# jaxb unexpected element error local:root

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

There seems to be several help topics concerning the issue but I haven't found a solution for which keeps bothering me.

I have to work with xml structure below:

```
<Customer xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/customer-example">
<Name>David Brent</Name>
<Notes>Big time</Notes>
</Customer>
```

It has other fields as well but I haven't been able to get it to work even with this minimal setup.

My pojo:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "name",
   "notes"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    public String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Notes", required = true)
    public String notes;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    ...
    ...

}
```

And the client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class); 
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Customer customer = (Customer)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("Data.xml"));

    System.out.println("Customer: "+customer.getName());

}
```

This throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"root"). Expected elements are <{}Customer>
```

What is local:root??? If I am trying to parse it with another way

```
 JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class); 
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
 StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource("Data.xml");
 JAXBElement<Customer> customer = (JAXBElement<Customer>).    
 unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource, Customer.class);

 customer.getValue.getName(); //is null
```

Does this problem have something to do with the xmlns definition in my xml??

Using Netbeans 7.3.1 with Java 1.7 OpenJDK

Answer (score 0):

The root element of `Data.xml` based on the exception is `root` and not `Customer` qualified by a namespace like you are expecting.  To get around this you can do like you have done and use an `unmarahal` method that takes a `Class` parameter.

The reason you are getting `null` for the `name` property is that you have not mapped the namespace qualification correctly.  You can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to do this.  The following will help you map to namespaces:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Blaise mentioned, you are lacking the namespace definition.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer", namespace="http://www.somedomain.com/customer-example")
```